# how to enlarge thumbnail image using window.setinterval and window.clearinterval/No Jquery

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to enlarge thumbnail images when clicked upon on the same and the centre of the page and then when clicked again to hide by using window.setinterval and window.clearinterval function only rather than setTimeout, so I don’t have to keep invoking it on every step of the animation. I also don't want to use Jquery.

Could anyone please help me and what I have been doing wrong.

Here is what has been done so far, my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="img.css" />
 <script src="img.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="untitled11.png" style="cursor:pointer"
         onclick="showImage(this.src, '1_large.png');" />
    <img src="untitled21.png" style="cursor:pointer"
         onclick="showImage(this.src, '2_large.png');" />
    <img src="untitled31.png" style="cursor:pointer"
         onclick="showImage(this.src, '3_large.png');" />

    <div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
        <img id="largeImg"
             style="height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript(Need help here)

```
    smSrc=document.getElementById('largeImg').src;
lgSrc=document.getElementById('largeImg').src;
var myVar;

    function showImage(smSrc, lgSrc) {
    myVar = window.setInterval(showLargeImage(), 1000); }
            unselectAll();


        function showLargeImage() {
           document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.display = 'block';

function setTimeout() {
     window.clearInterval(myVar); } 
        }
        function unselectAll() {
            if(document.selection)
                document.selection.empty();
            if(window.getSelection)
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

        }
```

My CSS (as like I said want the image to enlarge at the centre of the page)

```
            #largeImgPanel {
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DcRTh/1/ 
Above link is my coding but the images are not showing. However I can tell you so far on my website it displays the thumbnail images but when clicked upon it doesn't.

Please help me correct my javascript by using window.setinterval and not Jquery and setTmeout because I've looked online to solve my problem but haven't found the desired result. I'm new to programming so I'm not so good. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you even need setInterval setTimeout? You're not animating.  You're using both of those functions completely wrong as well read some documentation to see how to use them

Comment: I need to animate the images into a large version when it is clicked, that's why I need to use setinterval rather than setTimeout.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it's trying to animate. Sorry

Comment: You are not using them even basically correct.

Comment: I've read tutorials but they show the basics use of the methods. I'm not so good at it. It's ok :(